# Can you delete an opportunity record type in Visual Studio code?

Tags: opportunity, record-type, visualstudiocode

I am reading mixed information. Can an opportunity type be deleted?

Comment: If you want to do this then first you need to remove all active profiles from record type. and I would recommend updating all records that are associated with any of the Record Types you want to delete. Once those Record Types no longer have any records associated with them, then you should be fine to delete those as well.

Comment: On the profile level the reference to the opportunity record type is removed. The isActive is set to false for the opportunity record type. Should the opportunity type code be deleted from the object in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete record types through the API. You'll get an error like this:

```
=== Component Failures [1]
Type   Name       Problem
─────  ─────────  ─────────────────────────────────────
Error  Case.Test  Cannot delete record type through API
```

This restriction exists because some profiles may be associated with the record type, which would leave those profiles without a default record type.

You will need to manually delete the record type in the UI.